# How to decode this nested JSON string?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, gson

i tried many times to decode nested JSON string which consist of nested Array , i used `GSON()` to do that. and it's worked , but the problem is about objects inside this array don't be decoded from json, so i want your help :

JSON String :

```
{ "data" : { "current_condition" : [ { "cloudcover" : "75",
            "humidity" : "87",
            "observation_time" : "03:16 AM",
            "precipMM" : "1.5",
            "pressure" : "991",
            "temp_C" : "11",
            "temp_F" : "52",
            "visibility" : "7",
            "weatherCode" : "293",
            "weatherDesc" : [ { "value" : "Patchy light rain" } ],
            "weatherIconUrl" : [ { "value" : "http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0033_cloudy_with_light_rain_night.png" } ],
            "winddir16Point" : "SSW",
            "winddirDegree" : "210",
            "windspeedKmph" : "30",
            "windspeedMiles" : "19"
          } ],
      "request" : [ { "query" : "London, United Kingdom",
            "type" : "City"
          } ],
      "weather" : [ { "date" : "2014-01-03",
            "precipMM" : "6.9",
            "tempMaxC" : "10",
            "tempMaxF" : "50",
            "tempMinC" : "5",
            "tempMinF" : "41",
            "weatherCode" : "293",
            "weatherDesc" : [ { "value" : "Patchy light rain" } ],
            "weatherIconUrl" : [ { "value" : "http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0017_cloudy_with_light_rain.png" } ],
            "winddir16Point" : "SW",
            "winddirDegree" : "220",
            "winddirection" : "SW",
            "windspeedKmph" : "33",
            "windspeedMiles" : "21"
          } ]
    } }
```

my Code to decode this JSON :

```
HashMap HashMap = new Gson().fromJson(json, HashMap.class);
```

and it's output :

> {data={request=[{query=London, United Kingdom, type=City}],
>   current_condition=[{cloudcover=75, humidity=87, observation_time=03:16
>   AM, precipMM=1.5, pressure=991, temp_C=11, temp_F=52, visibility=7,
>   weatherCode=293, weatherDesc=[{value=Patchy light rain}],
>   weatherIconUrl=[{value=http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0033_cloudy_with_light_rain_night.png}],
>   winddir16Point=SSW, winddirDegree=210, windspeedKmph=30,
>   windspeedMiles=19}], weather=[{date=2014-01-03, precipMM=6.9,
>   tempMaxC=10, tempMaxF=50, tempMinC=5, tempMinF=41, weatherCode=293,
>   weatherDesc=[{value=Patchy light rain}],
>   weatherIconUrl=[{value=http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0017_cloudy_with_light_rain.png}],
>   winddir16Point=SW, winddirDegree=220, winddirection=SW,
>   windspeedKmph=33, windspeedMiles=21}]}}

so i want an ideal method to give me ability to enter this nested HashMap array and it's values , because my method don't give me ability to call nested values from this array

Thank you ,

Comment: Your code should work fine; you just need to cache the inner objects to HashMap.

Comment: See json.org for the JSON syntax.  It's quite easy to understand.

Comment: To access inner objects you simply "peel the onion", a layer at a time.  "data" gives you a Map from which you can access "current_condition".  That produces a List which contains one element, a Map containing "cloudcover", "humidity", "observation_time", etc.

Comment: `(Map) HashMap.get("data")` will get you the map that represents the value of the `"data"` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's worked after i did this method :

```
Type type = new TypeToken< HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap>>>>() {}.getType();

HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap>>> hashMap = new Gson().fromJson(API.getJSON(), type);    

com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap hash = hashMap.get("data").get("current_condition").get(0);

System.out.println("    "+hash.get("humidity")+"      ");
```

i know that your answers and my first method are true , but as i told you that i want to enter the entry nested array list inside this Json

Answer (score 2):

as the string represents a Hashmap inside another Hashmap you can use some thing like,

```
HashMap<String, HashMap> hashMap = new Gson().fromJson(json, HashMap.class);
```